# Insert graph from function call into subplots

Tags: function, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I have a function which produces exactly the graphs I need:

```
def graph(x, y, yName, dataset, colour, residuals = False, calc_tau = False):
    """
    Takes as an argument two arrays, one for x and one y, a string for the
    name of the y-variable, and two colours (which could be strings, values
    or iterators).
    Plots a scatter graph of the array against log(z), along with the best fit
    line, its equation and its regression coefficient, as well as Kendall's tau
    and the total number of points plotted.
    """

    arrayresults, arrayresids, arrayparams, arrayfit, arrayequation, arraytau = computeLinearStats(x,
                                                                      y,
                                                                     yName, calc_tau)
    count = np.count_nonzero(~np.logical_or(np.isnan(x), np.isnan(y)))
#    arrayequation = 'r\'' + yName +arrayequation[arrayequation.index('='):]
    plt.scatter(x, y,
#                label = arrayequation,
                s = 10,
                alpha = 0.5,
                c = colour)
    if calc_tau:                #if calc_tau is set to True, display the value
                                #in the legend along with equation, r and n
        plt.plot(x, arrayfit,
                 label = r'''%s
    r=%g
    $\tau$=%g
    n=%d'''%(arrayequation, arrayparams[2], arraytau[0], count),
                 c = colour)
    else:                       #otherwise just display equation, r and n
        plt.plot(x, arrayfit,
                 label = r'''%s
    $r=%g$
    $n=%d$
    $r^2n=%.2f$'''%(arrayequation, arrayparams[2], count, arrayresults.nobs*arrayparams[2]**2),
                 c = colour)
    legendfont = 16
    labelfont = 20
    plt.xlabel('$log_{10}(z)$', fontsize = labelfont)
    plt.ylabel('Magnitude combination, %s dataset'%dataset, fontsize = labelfont)
    plt.legend(fontsize = legendfont)
    plt.xticks(fontsize = labelfont)
    plt.yticks(fontsize = labelfont)
    plt.grid(True, which = 'both')
#    plt.title(r'The three best high-$r$ combinations in both Hunstead and MgII', fontsize = labelfont)
    if residuals:
        plotResids(x, y, yName, dataset, colour)
    plt.show()
    return arrayresults, arrayresids, arrayparams, arrayfit, arrayequation, arraytau
```

which I can call multiple times to produce, for example:

[image]
and
[image]

It's kind of an ad hoc function, but it produces the graphs how I want them to look. Is there an easy way of combining the graphs output by multiple calls to the function into a set of subplots? I've tried something like

```
x = sources['z']
    y1 = I-W2
    y2 = W3-U
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,1, sharex=True, sharey=False, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0})
    fig.suptitle('Graphs')
    ax[0].scatter(x, y1, c='red', s = 10, alpha = 0.3)
    ax[1].scatter(x, y2, c='purple', s = 10, alpha = 0.3)
```

but I'd like them with all the accoutrements. Ideally, I'd like `ax1` and `ax2` to call my graphing function and display the output in subplots. Is this possible?

EDIT: thanks to a comment, I'm able to use

```
x = sources['z']
y1 = I-W2
y2 = W3-U

fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,1, sharex=True, sharey=True, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0})
ax1 = qf.graph(x, y1, 'I-W2', dataset, 'blue', ax[0], residuals = False, calc_tau = False)  #2 rows, 1 column, first plot
ax2 = qf.graph(x, y2, 'W3-U', dataset, 'red', ax[1], residuals = False, calc_tau = False)  #2 rows, 1 column, second plot
fig.suptitle('Graphs')
```

to produce

[image]

but how can I get one graph into the top position (ax[0])?

Comment: The `graph` function should take an argument `ax` being the axes to plot to. Then you can call it with `graph(..., ax=ax[0])` and similar for `ax[1]`. You may be interested in readig the [coding styles](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#coding-styles) chapter in the usage guide.

Comment: You'd have to plot on the selected axis: `plt.plot(...)` selects the current axis (normally the last created) while `ax.plot(...)` plots on a selected axis `ax`. The same goes for `xlabel` (to be replaced by `ax.set_xlabel`), etc.

Comment: Though your example is not in line with your question any more.

Comment: Also, please only post [minimal working examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and convert your current question into one. This increases the chances of being answered, and, very much in the spirit of this site, provide a good references to others (not something highly specialised, that takes a lot of time to decipher).